# Is there a way to tell which spaceship parts the other civs have built?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a way to tell which spaceship parts the other civs have built, where they are, and how close they are to a science victory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! There is a way to see this.
Just open the victory progress screen and you'll see something like the picture below [image: victory progress]

If you then click on details for the science victory you'll see this [image: detail overview]

This will show you how far every nation has progressed towards completing the spaceship.

On my screenshots all nations are still unknown because I made this screenshots in a new game on turn 1.

Comment: And with regards to where they are - they will be in the capital, as that is where they must be assembled for victory purposes.

Comment: They don't *have* to be in the capital though, they might be being moved towards it after being build in some other city. (if my memory isn't feeding me nonsense anyway)

Comment: @Arperum Won't they only show up on the victory progress screen if they've been added to the ship in the capital? I think that's when the notification appears

Answer (score 0):

It only shows the parts added to the capital.
Although I don´t think CPU´s  will do this, Human Players can (and likely will) simply leave them outside their capital, until they have all 6 Parts completed, them move them in and add them all in a single turn, and the other players will only see the "Completed Apollo Project" Notification.
Therefore, getting visibility of enemy player´s capitols is important!